# Prove that there exists a Lebesgue Measurable subset $B$ of $A$ such that $\lambda(B)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A$ be a measurable subset of $\Bbb R$ and $\lambda(A)=1$ where $\lambda $ denotes the Lebesgue Measure on $\Bbb R$ .
>
> Prove that there exists a Lebesgue Measurable subset $B$ of $A$ such that $\lambda(B)=\frac{1}{2}$.

I have completed sections on Measure Theory from G.D.Baraa upto Lebesgue Measure but I am not getting any hints on how to solve this problem.Please give me some hints.

**Also please give me some names of books where I can find these sort of questions and try to solve them**.

Comment: What about $\frac 1 2 A : = \left \{\frac x 2\ :\ x \in A \right \}\ $ @Learnmore?

Comment: @Anacardium; How do you know that $\frac{A}{2}\subset A$?

Answer (score 11):

The function
$$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}\mathbb{1}_A(t)\,dt $$
is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) and ranges from $0$ to $1$ since $\mu(A)=1$. By the intermediate value property of continuous functions we have that for some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ F(x_0)=\frac{1}{2} $$
holds, hence $\mu\left(A\cap(-\infty,x_0]\right)=\frac{1}{2}$ as wanted.